# In a constructive order/lattice theory are the arbitrary join and the weak suprema the same?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-theory, constructive-mathematics, intuitionism

For a poset $X$ we define an upperbound $w \in X$ of a subset $S \subseteq X$ to be a weak-supremum if

$(\forall a \in S (a \leq b)) \implies w \leq b$.

While a supremum is defined more carefully (in terms of an excess relation $\not\leq$ on $X$). That is, we define and upperbound $s \in X$ of an inhabited subset $S \subseteq X$ to be a supremum if

$\forall x \in X(s \not\leq x \implies \exists a \in S (a \not\leq x))$,

This differentiation between suprema primarily comes up in constructive analysis when the poset $X = \mathbb{R}$. But, I am currently studying lattice theory constructively and the question began to arise. Given a poset $X$ and a subset $S \subseteq X$ how do we define the join of $S$, $\bigvee S$?

Comment: In any case $\forall a\in S(a\le b)$ precisely means that $b$ is an upper bound of $S$. Hence your definition of weak-supremum is the definition of the least upper bound, which is the same as join. It is also what I would call supremum. To clarify its relation with your definition of supremum one would need to know precise axiomatics for your relation $\not\le$.

Comment: If the leading example is $\mathbb R$ then maybe $\nleq$ is just intended to be $>$. The second displayed formula needs a quantifier over $x$.

Comment: Maybe what you're looking for is the notion of **continuous lattice** (or just dcpo).

Comment: @PaulTaylor I agree that I need to quantify x, but the choice of an excess relation is neccesary to keep things working in general for posets.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე The axiomatics of an excess relation should be shared. I originally thought they were unnecesary and beyond the scope of the question. Your are correct in saying the two formulas describe the same object, classically. My question pertains to the distinction that arises due to the intuitionstic interpretation.

Comment: Note that since your stronger notion of supremum is a formal De Morgan dual of the ordinary one, it can be obtained from the [antithesis translation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.07518), which also supplies a list of axioms for $\nleq$ (Theorem 8.3).

Comment: Unless I misunderstand something fundamental here, it is constructively valid that what you call weak-supremum coincides with the join - in the sense that  the set of your weak-suprema is equal to the set of joins (and is a subsingleton). As for your supremum, it is different from these simply because its definition depends on another relation. Maybe @MikeShulman can provide an answer for it.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Yes, I agree -- what Toucanlan calls the "weak supremum" is the same as the join, and I've never heard it called anything but plain "supremum" even constructively.  I would call the other something like a "strong supremum"; I'm not sure if there is an additional question being asked about it.

Comment: @MikeShulman: I’ve come across “supremum” used for the stronger notion (in the reals) in some constructive analysis literature — if I remember right, the Bishop + Bridges book uses that terminology.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine yes the Bishop Analysis book is where I drew the terminology from.